# How to enable Identity Platform in Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I cannot seem to enable Google Identity Platform via Terraform.  I have this in my `main.tf` file:

```
variable "project_id" {
  description = "GCP Project ID as a string"
  type        = string
  default     = "myproject"
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "4.51.0"
    }
    google-beta = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google-beta"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }

  }
}

provider "google" {
  credentials = file("credentials.json")
  project     = var.project_id
  region      = "us-central1"
  zone        = "us-central1-c"
  billing_project = var.project_id 
}

# Configures the provider to use the resource block's specified project for quota checks.
provider "google-beta" {
  credentials           = file("credentials.json")
  user_project_override = true
}

# Configures the provider to not use the resource block's specified project for quota checks.
# This provider should only be used during project creation and initializing services.
provider "google-beta" {
  alias                 = "no_user_project_override"
  user_project_override = false
}

# Enables required APIs.
resource "google_project_service" "default" {
  provider = google-beta.no_user_project_override
  project  = var.project_id
  for_each = toset([
    "cloudbilling.googleapis.com",
    "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com",
    "firebase.googleapis.com",
    "serviceusage.googleapis.com",
    "identitytoolkit.googleapis.com",
    "cloudidentity.googleapis.com"
  ])
  service = each.key

  # Don't disable the service if the resource block is removed by accident.
  disable_on_destroy = false
}

# Enables Firebase services for the new project created above.
resource "google_firebase_project" "default" {
  provider = google-beta
  project  = var.project_id

  # Waits for the required APIs to be enabled.
  depends_on = [
    google_project_service.default
  ]
}

resource "google_firebase_web_app" "basic" {
  provider        = google-beta
  project         = var.project_id
  display_name    = "xxy"
  deletion_policy = "DELETE"
  depends_on      = [google_firebase_project.default]
}
```

If I simplify things and simply have:

```
...
resource "google_project_service" "identity_platform" {
  project = var.project_id 
  service = "cloudidentity.googleapis.com"
}
```

I still have no luck.

When I do `terraform apply` it says it was successful. I get no errors, yet when I go the GCP UI at https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google-cloud-platform/customer-identity?project=myproject

it still says it's not enabled and presents a button to enable it.

Comment: Did you figure out how to enable this? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Bypass [the marketplace Customer Identity page](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google-cloud-platform/customer-identity) and go directly to the [Customer Identity console](https://console.cloud.google.com/customer-identity).

Answer (score 0):

See the example from the [Google Terraform Provider identity_platform_config](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/identity_platform_config), you need to add a default config:

```
resource "google_identity_platform_config" "default" {
  project = google_project.default.project_id
  ...
  # Quota is a good idea to save you from abuse
  quota {
    sign_up_quota_config {
      quota = 1000
      start_time = ""
      quota_duration = "7200s"
    }
  }
}
```